# Searching by name through multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that, besides other information, contains names. I want to search for a name and get the field 'unique_id'.

The fields that could contain the name (or part of it) are:

```
f_name1, l_name1, f_name2, l_name2, prop_name
```

Now let's say the database contains this entry:

```
unqiue_id = 1, 
f_name1   = 'Barack',
l_name1   = 'Obama', 
f_name2   = 'Michelle', 
l_name2   = 'Obama', 
prop_name = 'White House',
...
```

and I have this string given in php:

```
$q = 'Barack Obama'; //or 'Michelle' or 'White House' or ...
```

What's the sql to get the 'unqiue_id' from that row?

```
SELECT unique_id FROM members WHERE (?)
```

One idea I had was to explode(' ', $q) and use LIKE '%...%' for everything and somehow count the number of conditions that are true and then ORDER BY that but I don't know if that's possible an if how to do it in SQL.

Edit1:

I came up with this solution thanks to 'PM 77-1's comment:

```
SELECT unique_id
FROM members
WHERE CONCAT( f_name1, l_name1, f_name2, l_name2, prop_name ) LIKE '%Barack%Obama%'
```

(replacing white-spaces with '%' in php)

However this only works if the input string is in the correct order...

Comment: Will your `$q` always list key words in the their original order?  Or can you have, for example "Obama Barack"?

Comment: theoretically yes but I'd be happy with a solution for that just works with the original order How would you do that? Replace the white-spaces with % and use LIKE ?

Comment: something like `WHERE CONCAT(f_name1,  ' ', l_name1,  ' ', f_name2,  ' ', l_name2, prop_name) LIKE CONCAT('%', $q, '%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
select t.*
from table t
where $p like concat('%', f_name1, '%') or
      $p like concat('%', l_name1, '%') or
      $p like concat('%', f_name2, '%') or
      $p like concat('%', l_name2, '%') or
      $p like concat('%', prop_name, '%')
order by (($p like concat('%', f_name1, '%') ) +
          ($p like concat('%', l_name1, '%') ) +
          ($p like concat('%', f_name2, '%') ) +
          ($p like concat('%', l_name2, '%') ) +
          ($p like concat('%', prop_name, '%') ) desc;
```

This solves the problem as described in the question.  But, you are possibly better off with a full text search.  The place to start with learning about this is the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look into the full text search documentation. Also I assume your $p should be my $q?

Comment: Shouldn't it be concat('%', field, '%') instead of concat('%', field) ?